# TFS 2012 Shelve

Tags: tfs, shelve

When I shelve some code in VS 2012 to TFS 2012, my changes will be uploaded to a server or kept locally, and when I check in will these changes upload all shelves at same time to the server?

Comment: Shelving a shelveset always writes all files that are "Included" to the server.  Whether it is kept locally depends on whether your check "Preserve changes locally" checkbox or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a shelveset, the shelveset is created on the server so your changes are at least stored on the server. You can choose whether you want to preserve your changes locally. If you do choose not to preserve your changes locally, the changes on the files that are included in the shelveset are undone.

Shelvesets are independent from check-ins, meaning that you always check in the changes that are contained in a workspace. It does not matter whether they originate from local changes or un-shelving one (or more) shelvesets. A check-in does not affect any shelvesets, they will stay on the server.

For details on shelvesets see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx).